# Sitecore webforms for marketers and general link

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a webform that has a "create item" action. The target item has a "general link" field. I can't find the correct way to populate this field. the other fields are saved correctly, the general link is always blank.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go here would be to create the item of the template you're creating programatically and then put a link value into it using one of the link options.

If you then go to 'View' and tick the raw values option you can see how it formats the link. If you're using a General link field, you'll likely find that the formatting needs to be in a specific way. If you do some searching on the web/Sitecore doco, you'll be able to find some examples of people handing all the various link options.

as opposed to just plonking your link into a single line text field or something like that which is just plain text..

Comment: The value of webforms for marketers is that advanced users can create input form for items without needing to program the functionality for a specific form again and again. If I have to create a specific save action for every template, I'm losing the most important feature on wfm.

Comment: Are you not creating an item through code and populating the values? Can you be more specific about what the issue is if not?

Comment: I'm creating an Item via Webforms for marketers. wfm gives you an interface where you can link the fields on your form with the fields on the item. Ideally without a single line of code, so advanced users can create forms. The wfm engine seems to have problems associating fields with a general link type of field